# vuejs what is the easiest way to display the value of the selected item in the drop down. I am already using v-model in one area

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejs for a select dropdown. I am already using v-model in one portion of the dropdown. I have a list where I will have different option names, and dont think having v-model in each one is a good idea. I do want to display the "value" of the selection on the screen though.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   selected:'',
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

{{value}}
   <select v-model="selected" class="hide">
                    <option value=''></option>
                    <option value='Act'>test1</option>
                    <option value='Advertising'>My AD</option>
              
                </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code "selected" holds the value of the selected option from dropdown and updates if you select another option.
for example if you click "My AD" in dropdown, you see "My AD" in the span below.

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>My AD</option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

Comment: guess what i want to know is--my text may differ from what is inside of value. I would want test 1 to show instead of Act. How would i handle that?

Comment: @Vzupo if you don't define value in the option,  innerText automatically is used as value

Comment: so i want MY AD to show instead of Advertising. It still shows advertising

Comment: I tested again just now to make sure and pasted the exact template that worked. If there is another issue on your side I wouldn't know.